# Angular2 checkbox - uncheck event

Tags: angular

Hello I have dropdown menu with checkboxes and I have a problem with call function when click on dropdown menu item. Here is my code:

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li *ngFor="let filter of column.filters">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="" #checkbox [(ngModel)]="filter.checked" 
                 (ngModelChange)="onSelectFilter(column)">{{filter.value}}</label>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Function `onSelectFilter()` is not called when checkbox is checked (I need to call with uncheck).
What event I must use when I need call method with check and uncheck? 
Thanks

Comment: [**It works for me**](http://plnkr.co/edit/2U3vDKQcBWlz1MXAsMTe?p=info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take away the value="" and just set the initial model (filter.checked) to what you want it to start out as.

The value="" thing will just get in the way! :)

Also, it seems like you're using an ngFor to give you a list of checkboxes... but in the (ngModelChange), you are passing through the entire column (which has multiple checkboxes)... This may not be what you are intending to do?

eg. I think this might be more what you want?

```
(ngModelChange)="onSelectFilter(filter)"
```

Comment: Thanks, when I edited checkbox, it works: `<li *ngFor="let filter of column.filters">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="filter.checked" 
                 (ngModelChange)="onSelectFilter(column)">{{filter.value}}</label>
            </div>
          </li>`

Comment: Excellent :) It's very easy to get caught out doing little "standard html" things that angular doesn't like!